# Compatibility-Mode doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, process, compatibility, uac

I used to play the game Freelancer, which originally was designed to work with win98/Me/2000/xp, with Windows Xp/Vista/7. Now I upgraded to Win 10 and it doesn't run anymore.

The problem is, that it asks for additional rights and tells me to log in again with admin rights, though I have admin rights. I heard, that this is a problem to be expected with older programs, but that you can fix it with compatibility-mode.

That's what I have tried so far:

- Different compatibility-modes(XP(different SPs)/Vista/7/98/Me)
- Run the shortcut with admin-rights
- run the .exe with admin-rights
- reinstall game
- disabling UAC
- create a task with the task-scheduler with highest priority
- set admin-rights in the shortcut compatibility settings

None of this works.
I noticed that the game-process starts, when I try to open it without admin-rights, but then I get the "you need admin-rights" error and it shuts down.
When I'm running it with admin-rights/compatibility-mode it doesn't start but therefore a lot of .dll processes start and close immediately.

Comment: Compatibility Mode uses a shim, it fixes most problems, but not all nor does it claim to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently caused by the anti-piracy measures used in Freelancer which do not work correctly with Windows 10 as mentioned [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/how-can-i-get-freelancer-to-work-in-windows-10/45147266-2016-4513-87d6-c485b789b39c). A resolution for this is to use a no-cd crack to disable the protection. You can probably get one [here](http://www.gamecopyworld.com/). (There may be legal issues surrounding this in your country. Consult a lawyer if you are unsure.)

Comment: Possible work around.  http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?697164-Possible-fix-to-win10-issues-with-secdrv-sys